# How do I configure sshguard in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, iptables, ufw, sshd

I have previously used sshguard successfully on Ubuntu 16.04 by simply installing the `sshguard` package. When I tried to do the same on 20.04, however, I discovered that it was only *mostly* working: sshguard was logging the blocks, and adding them to `iptables --list sshguard`, but the blocks weren’t actually taking effect.

What do I need to do to get `sshguard` fully working in Focal Fossa?

Answer (score 5):

I found the [Arch Wiki page on sshguard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshguard#UFW), which advises adding the following to `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, just below the `# allow all on loopback` block:

```
# hand off control for sshd to sshguard
:sshguard - [0:0]
-A ufw-before-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j sshguard
```

Adding this to the file and doing `sudo systemctl restart ufw` seems to have done the trick.

---

However, there's one other config change you should make: the sshguard.conf file that comes with Ubuntu will [cause sshguard to retrigger on its own log messages](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sshguard/+bug/1881459), instantly banning the IP as soon as it makes a single mistake. (This bug seems to have been introduced in the upstream debian package; the examples provided in the sshguard source don't have this problem.) To fix this, edit `/etc/sshguard/sshguard.conf` and remove the `SYSLOG_FACILITY` options from the `LOGREADER` setting, replacing them with `-t sshd` (and possibly other services you want sshguard to monitor.) The setting should look like this:

```
LOGREADER="LANG=C /bin/journalctl -afb -p info -n1 -o cat -t sshd"
```

With these two changes it now seems to be working as expected.